# Parsing JIRA webhook comments

Tags: python, json, jira, webhooks

I am trying to parse JIRA webhook comment section properly. Now, following code works well for the first comment:

```
data = request.json
jira_comment = data['issue']['fields']['comment']['comments'][0].get('body')
```

However, every time new webhook is fired, for example, new comment is added, I can only receive the first comment in the JSON-message. If I could somehow identify each comment from another or only parse always the last comment of the issue. What would be the best way to do it or is it even possible since JIRA webhook JSON looks broken (multiple 'body' keys).

See JSON data below, to make it cleaner, use this http://jsbeautifier.org/:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1443024903340,
    "webhookEvent": "jira:issue_updated",
    "user": {
        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
        "name": "jhdoe",
        "key": "jhdoe",
        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
        },
        "displayName": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    "issue": {
        "id": "10300",
        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10300",
        "key": "DEMO-6",
        "fields": {
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
                "id": "3",
                "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
                "iconUrl": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
                "name": "Task",
                "subtask": false
            },
            "components": [],
            "timespent": null,
            "timeoriginalestimate": null,
            "description": "Hey",
            "project": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/project/10000",
                "id": "10000",
                "key": "DEMO",
                "name": "DEMO",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10011",
                    "24x24": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10011",
                    "16x16": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10011",
                    "32x32": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10011"
                }
            },
            "fixVersions": [],
            "aggregatetimespent": null,
            "resolution": null,
            "timetracking": {},
            "customfield_10006": null,
            "attachment": [],
            "customfield_10009": "0|i0000f:",
            "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "workratio": -1,
            "summary": "Comment test",
            "lastViewed": "2015-09-23T19:14:11.979+0300",
            "watches": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/DEMO-6/watchers",
                "watchCount": 1,
                "isWatching": true
            },
            "creator": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                "name": "jhdoe",
                "key": "jhdoe",
                "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                    "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                    "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                    "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                },
                "displayName": "John Doe",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "subtasks": [],
            "created": "2015-09-21T17:39:14.518+0300",
            "reporter": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                "name": "jhdoe",
                "key": "jhdoe",
                "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                    "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                    "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                    "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                },
                "displayName": "John Doe",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "customfield_10000": null,
            "aggregateprogress": {
                "progress": 0,
                "total": 0
            },
            "priority": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/priority/2",
                "iconUrl": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/images/icons/priorities/high.png",
                "name": "High",
                "id": "2"
            },
            "customfield_10001": null,
            "customfield_10100": "1234",
            "customfield_10200": null,
            "labels": [],
            "customfield_10004": null,
            "environment": null,
            "timeestimate": null,
            "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
            "versions": [],
            "duedate": null,
            "progress": {
                "progress": 0,
                "total": 0
            },
            "comment": {
                "startAt": 0,
                "maxResults": 3,
                "total": 3,
                "comments": [{
                    "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10300/comment/10600",
                    "id": "10600",
                    "author": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "body": "Comment 1",
                    "updateAuthor": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "created": "2015-09-23T19:05:26.593+0300",
                    "updated": "2015-09-23T19:08:07.010+0300"
                }, {
                    "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10300/comment/10601",
                    "id": "10601",
                    "author": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "body": "Comment 2",
                    "updateAuthor": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "created": "2015-09-23T19:08:13.644+0300",
                    "updated": "2015-09-23T19:08:13.644+0300"
                }, {
                    "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10300/comment/10606",
                    "id": "10606",
                    "author": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "body": "Comment 3",
                    "updateAuthor": {
                        "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=jhdoe",
                        "name": "jhdoe",
                        "key": "jhdoe",
                        "emailAddress": "john.doe@corp.com",
                        "avatarUrls": {
                            "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=48",
                            "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=24",
                            "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=16",
                            "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f94b6b6c15d155f4d4b3b2c05509ab0a?d=mm&s=32"
                        },
                        "displayName": "John Doe",
                        "active": true,
                        "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                    },
                    "created": "2015-09-23T19:13:24.836+0300",
                    "updated": "2015-09-23T19:14:04.464+0300"
                }]
            },
            "issuelinks": [],
            "votes": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/issue/DEMO-6/votes",
                "votes": 0,
                "hasVoted": false
            },
            "worklog": {
                "startAt": 0,
                "maxResults": 20,
                "total": 0,
                "worklogs": []
            },
            "assignee": null,
            "updated": "2015-09-23T19:15:03.338+0300",
            "status": {
                "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/status/10000",
                "description": "",
                "iconUrl": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/images/icons/subtask.gif",
                "name": "To Do",
                "id": "10000",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "http://192.168.10.58:8080/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
                    "id": 2,
                    "key": "new",
                    "colorName": "blue-gray",
                    "name": "To Do"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "changelog": {
        "id": "10611",
        "items": [{
            "field": "Custom ID",
            "fieldtype": "custom",
            "from": null,
            "fromString": null,
            "to": null,
            "toString": "1234"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your comment section in the json is a list of dicts so you can always get the last in the list then call .get('body')

```
jira_comment = data['issue']['fields']['comment']['comments'][-1].get('body')
```

this works because in python negative numbers in an array index are treated as going backwards in the array. so -1 gives you the last item in the array.

Does your code work when there is no comments at all? 
If it doesn't consider checking that the length of the the comments array is greater than 0 or just wrap it in a try except block.

Comment: Thank you mister, it worked as expected. Actual code works because I added if-block to check it.

Answer (score 1):

When a comment is added, the request body should contain `data['comment']`, which will contain the comment that triggered the issue update. You can compare `data['comment']['created']` and `data['comment']['updated']` to figure if the comment is new or if the comment has been edited.

see https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks

Comment: This was very helpful for me. My question was actually, how do I know when someone has commented on a ticket. I couldn't see the forest for the trees and ended up only seeing the array of comments inside data->issue->fields->comment->comments   -   your reply clued be in to the fact that data->comment->body would get me the body of the comment which initiated the webhook. Thank you!